# Struts Error auto converting string to garbage value

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am taking String value and other data from the database and set in a string of class object but i showing string in the web page its showing garbage value like -3892 something like that

In Class TravelVO the String

```
private String travelCombnationId;

//Setter getters
public String getTravelCombnationId() {
    return travelCombnationId;
}
public void setTravelCombnationId(String travelCombnationId) {
    this.travelCombnationId = travelCombnationId;
}
```

In Database Class

```
while (rs.next()) {
    travel = new TravelVO();
    travel.setTravelId(rs.getLong("TRAVEL_ID"));
    travel.setTravelCombnationId(rs.getString("TRAVEL_COMB_ID")); // Showing Value properly here
    System.out.println(travel.getTravelCombnationId());
    travel.setTravelReason(rs.getString("TRAVEL_REASON"));
    myApprovedRequests.add(travel);
}
```

Action Class

```
iAcceptForwardList = TravelDAO.getInstance().myPendingRequest();
```

JSP PAGE

```
<s:iterator value="iAcceptForwardList" var="quesvar" status="questat">
    <tr>
       <td><s:text name="%{iAcceptForwardList[#questat.index].travelCombnationId}"/></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

when I getting in DAO its properly Showing the value

Showing in sysout T-268-300-2018-Jul

Its Showing value on jsp page   -72737

Please help..

Comment: Unrelated, but why you you set a `var` in the iterator, then ignore it and access the list by index? (Which, depending on the list implementation, could also be some wasted effort.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Property instead of directly using object variable

`<s:property value="%{iAcceptForwardList[#questat.index].travelCombnationId}" />`